# Java Collections: Is Object Added Directly Added To Collection?

Tags: java, collections

I know that when I add an object to some collections such as a LinkedList, the element is not added directly to the collection; in actuality a node is added to the collection which provides the linking functionality, and this node has a reference to the Object that I add to the collection.  Is this true for all Java collection classes?  For example when I do the following:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Car");
```

Is the String object "Car" added directly to the list, or just a node is added to the list which points to "Car"?

Also, can I consider this a proxy design pattern?

Comment: `ArrayList` stores the added `String` direcly in the internally used array.

Comment: @MrSmith42: no it doesn't. Since String is a reference type, the ArrayList stores a reference to the String in its internal array. In fact Collections such as ArrayLists can only store reference objects, and does it always this way.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: That is what I meant (of cause the String is not copied). The reference in not wrapped in an extra object such as a Node.

Comment: what difference does it make if it stores directly or otherwise? Every object in Java is reference allocated and referred, except stack types(such as int, char, and other basic types)

Comment: @MrSmith42: well that is the crux of the question and must be clearly stated.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I understand the question the way: Is there a wrapper like a `Ǹode`-object? And the answer related to ' SrrayList'  is *NO*. By the way also in the `Node` of a `LinkedList` is a reference to the added object.

Comment: I agree that I didn't word the question well enough.

Comment: @Aniket:  Makes a big difference whether it is added directly or it is wrapped in a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArrayList in Java uses array to store the references to objects, thus it has nothing to do with Proxy pattern. You can see that for yourself, [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) is a link to it's OpenJDK implementation. Line 103 has the relevant piece of code.

```
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

You can also compare it to [LinkedList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) which uses Nodes to store references to next and previous element in `List`.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Would you consider it a proxy pattern in the case of LinkedList?  In that case, the element added is wrapped in a Node that is added to the LinkedList?  I'm not sure whether proxy or decorator pattern would fit this scenario.

Comment: Actually primitive values are NOT stored in ArrayLists or any Collection for that matter.  You can only store Objects.  Java will convert primitives to their Object equivalent (int -> Integer, float -> Float, etc) and those can be stored in the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

No adding elements to a LinkedList is NOT the proxy pattern.  The proxy pattern is a creational pattern.  There is no creation taking place within the LinkedList with respect to what it contains.  The fact that the Node wraps an Object isn't enough to qualify it as a proxy.  The wrapping node also doesn't implement a shared interface with it and the object contained with in the Collection.

A proxy is an object that can stand in place of another object so that shared interface is important.  This stand in object can save memory, time, or both by creating the real object on demand.  It can also choose to destroy the object when its not needed.  The proxy controls the lifetime of the object it wraps which is a hallmark of the Proxy pattern.  The Node within the collection doesn't control the life time of the object it points to because it was given that object it wraps.

For example, say we have an application that connects to many databases, but it doesn't always need to connect to all of them all at once.  We could implement a special DataSource that will create the underlying DataSource only when a connection is requested.  It could also close down the DataSource when you don't an active connection (say when the last connection handed out is closed).

This is similar to how connection pooling is implemented in most connection pooling libraries.  The underlying DataSource just provides a connection to the DB, but the connection pooling is layered on top of the DataSource and provides pooling without the client realizing its happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually **look at the source code** of `ArrayList` etc.

An `ArrayList` uses an `Object[]` array internally, so it does not involve extra wrappers, but it stores the object references directly. So definitely no "proxy" here.

If you put in primitive types, they will be autoboxed as Objects though. I wouldn't call this an instance of the proxy pattern either.

If you look for the proxy pattern, have a look at RMI.